# Can we integrate Dynamodb with Wavemaker?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dashboard, wavemaker

Is there any way out I can integrate Dynamodb with Wavemaker?

I have found that to do so the database must have Hibernate and jdbc driver, but hibernate is not there in Dynamo instead DynamoDBMapper is present.

Is there anyway I can do the integration.
Or if there is any dashboard i can implement over dynamo to do the analysis of the data would also work.

Answer (score 0):

No. DynamoDB doesn't have Hibernate / JDBC connection. Those are technologies for RDMBS (SQL) databases. DynamoDB is a NoSQL product. The two don't match.

Comment: Thanks :) But is there any other dashboard available that can be integrated with Dynamodb?

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that there is no native JDBC connection to DynamoDB data, there are 3rd party drivers out there that allow you to connect to your non-relational data in a relational way.

CData Software (full disclosure: my employer) has built a JDBC Driver for Amazon DynamoDB. You can read more about it and download a free trial [here](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/dynamodb/jdbc/).

Unfortunately, we don't have any direct articles for connecting to your DynamoDB from within WaveMaker, but since our drivers are written to match JDBC standards, you shouldn't have any trouble connecting. I can tell you that your JDBC URL to connect to our driver will look similar to the following:

```
jdbc:dynamodb:Access Key=xxx;Secret Key=xxx;Domain=amazonaws.com;Region=OREGON;
```

If you run into any issues or have any questions, our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) will be happy to help.